# Ansible copy - is there any difference if dest directory ends with or without /

Tags: ansible, copy

I'm doing ansible remote copy, have a question about dest, is there any difference if the dest ends with or without /?

1. dest: /tmp/dest
2. dest: /tmp/dest/

I've tried with and without /, looks like both of them do the copy.

```
    - name: copy the properties file to dest
      copy:
        src: /tmp/src/{{ item }}
        dest: /tmp/dest
        remote_src: yes
      with_items:
        - runtime.properties
        - default.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are copying a directory, it doesn't matter whether or not the target path ends with `/`.  In both cases, Ansible first ensure the target directory exists and then copy the source directory into the target directory.  That is, given either:

```
- copy:
    src: src_dir
    dest: /tmp/dest/
```

Or:

```
- copy:
    src: src_dir
    dest: /tmp/dest
```

In both cases, Ansible will first create `/tmp/dest` if it does not exist and will then create `/tmp/dest/src_dir` and populate it with the contents of `src_dir`.

However, if you are copying a *file* the situation is a little different.  If the target destination `/tmp/dest` *does not exist*, this playbook will create a file named `/tmp/dest`:

```
- copy:
    src: src_file
    dest: /tmp/dest
```

However, if you add a trailing path to the destination, then Ansible will first create the directory `/tmp/dest` and then create the file `/tmp/dest/src_file`.

```
- copy:
    src: src_file
    dest: /tmp/dest/
```

If a directory named `/tmp/dest` already exists, then both of the above examples will do the same thing (create `/tmp/dest/src_file`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for very detailed explanation!! however, have a further question about copy file overwrite. /tmp/dest already exists, i'd like to copy file1 to dest, if file1 already exists in /tmp/dest, then overwrite it. I've given force: yes, for the dest, should i use /tmp/dest or /tmp/dest/?

```- copy:
    src: src_dir
    dest: /tmp/dest/
    #dest: /tmp/dest
    force: yes
```

Comment: `/tmp/dest/` -- with a trailing slash -- always refers to a directory. If your target is a file, you will not use a trailing slash.